# Integrate django with django-lfs

Tags: django, e-commerce, django-lfs

I try to integrate django-ifs like a django app without using buildout. Now I can start server by after syncdb django create all model. I can manage shop , add product BUT when I try to display product on page.Its display

Exception Value:`Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'Shop' object has no attribute 'content_type'`

Exception Location:`/home/siraset/works/env-brille/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_portlets-1.0b2-py2.6.egg/portlets/templatetags/portlets_tags.py in portlet_slot, line 21`

Comment: How did you do it( integrating it without buildout)? i have the same problem and i don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at Django portlet's source, you will see that this part has changed in a newer version! It was using an object'c content type as a cache key before, but i assume not every model should have a reference ContentType, so they changed it: http://bitbucket.org/diefenbach/django-portlets/diff/portlets/templatetags/portlets_tags.py?diff2=796ee52ef3d1&diff1=791c36e884ff
So check out a newer version!